# spatial data query

Tags: sql, postgresql, geospatial, postgis, spatial-query

I have the following query which does a self join with a table and outputs all the points of intersections between lines.

```
insert into road_intersection
select nextval('road_intersection_id_seq'), a.road_id, b.road_id, st_intersection(a.road, b.road), st_centroid(st_intersection(a.road, b.road))
from polygon_road a, polygon_road b
where st_intersects(a.road, b.road) AND a.road_id!=b.road_id
```

BUT it outputs duplicate values for each point of intersection since it computes the point of intersection for each road. EG:

```
70;71;POINT_OF_INTERSECTION

71;70;POINT_OF_INTERSECTION
```

`70` AND `71` are both `id` values of two distinct roads. As you can see the point of intersection has been computed twice for the same two roads.

Any suggestions how i can solve this issue and only one point of intersection would be computed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
select nextval('road_intersection_id_seq'), 
       a.road_id, 
       b.road_id, 
       st_intersection(a.road, b.road), 
       st_centroid(st_intersection(a.road, b.road))
from polygon_road a, polygon_road b
where st_intersects(a.road, b.road) 
  --AND a.road_id!=b.road_id --not needed any more

  AND a.road_id < b.road_id
```

It will leave only one of the intersections (the one, where the first road has smaller id)